# How to add auto play to an image slider javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I got this open-source slider which I have rewritten and adjusted some part of the javascript code to suit my need.

But what I could not tweak to my desire was making the slider play the image or slide automatically on page load.

```
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
const galleryControlsContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-controls');
const galleryControls = ['previous', 'add', 'next'];
const galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

class Carousel {
  constructor(container, items, controls) {
    this.carouselContainer = container;
    this.carouselControls = controls;
    this.carouselArray = [...items];
  }

  updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });

    this.carouselArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
      el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
  }

  setCurrentState(direction) {

    if (direction.className == 'gallery-controls-previous') {
      this.carouselArray.unshift(this.carouselArray.pop());
    } else {
      this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    }
    
    this.updateGallery();
  }

  
  setControls() {
    this.carouselControls.forEach(control => {
          
      if(control == 'add'){
      }
      else if(control == 'previous'){
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = "assets/images/icon_prev.png";
          galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(img).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;
          galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(img).id = `mr40`;
      }
      else if(control == 'next'){
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = "assets/images/icon_next.png";
          galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(img).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;
      }
      
    });
  }
 
  useControls() {
    const triggers = [...galleryControlsContainer.childNodes];

    triggers.forEach(control => {
      control.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (control.className == 'gallery-controls-add') {} else {
          this.setCurrentState(control);
        }

      });
    });
  }
}

const exampleCarousel = new Carousel(galleryContainer, galleryItems, galleryControls);

exampleCarousel.setControls();
exampleCarousel.useControls();
```

That is the javascript above.

Below is a sample html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
</head>
<body>


                                <div class="gallery">
                                    <div class="gallery-container">
                                            <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-1" src="cimg1.jpg" data-index="1">
                                            <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-2" src="cimg2.jpg" data-index="2">
                                            <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-3" src="cimg3.jpg" data-index="3">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gallery-controls"></div>
                                  </div>
                            
<script src="slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I would be pleased to have someone help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this being done with `options` being passed when constructing the object (slider in this case). In your case the options would include `autoplay: boolean` and `slideDelay: number` or something similar.

Adding the functionality should be as simple as using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in order to execute the `next` functionality for the slider. So, instead of acting on a mouse click, it would act on the interval timer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval